# Magento - load a widget instance in a template file

Tags: magento

I have created a custom widget and I want to load an instance of it in a phtml template file.

How can I load my Widget by "Widget ID" or "Widget Instance Title" ??

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also call it programmatically in the template file like this:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock(‘catalog/product_widget_new’, null, array(‘products_count’=>5, ‘template’=>’catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml’))->toHtml();
```

Ofcourse you need to replace the variables with your own.

Comment: unfortunately that does not responds to my question; 
I don't need custom variables in my widget, but needd to load an instance of the widget oder an other...

Comment: Those are for passing variables, but you can also just call the widget without passing the variables. What do you mean with "oder an other"? You are just trying to get the widget in a phtml right?

Comment: soryy, "oder" was german, it means "or". Thanks for help, have you an example how can I specify the Widget id in the syntax, Thanks a lot.